# VB NET XPath won't select a node based on a value

Tags: xpath

I have a node on an XML file for which I need to select. To select, I have to look at one of the element's value. Once selected, I will then arrange for the entire node to be deleted from the file.

We have a framework that deals with the selecting of nodes however I currently receive the following error: `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`

All the framework does is takes in the XMLElement and XPath, and uses what looks to be a defined function named `.selectNode(xPath)` to find the node. This is what throws the above error.

My XML Data set(which is the XMLElement) looks like this:

```
<topParent value1="a" value2 = "b">
     <att1 value3="c" value4 = "d">
        <myline data="e" moredata="f" />
        <myline data="g" moredata="h" />
     </att1>
</topParent>
```

and my xPath for selecting looks like : `//myline/[@moredata='h']`

The idea is to select "myline" node when "moreData" equals h

I've only come across XPath in the last few hours but I can't see why this node isn't being selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put a slash before a predicate. It's wrong syntax.
Just use

```
//myline[@moredata='h']
```

to select all the `myline` elements which satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been going over the syntax for most of the day and that slash had just gone straight over my head!